# Got an error in magento connect for installing any extension

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

In my store have magento community edition - 7.1.

I try to install extension using magento store, but I got an error like this for all type of extensions

**community/Dropifi_Dropificontactwidget: Could not resolve host: connect20.magentocommerce.com; Host not found**

I placed this key for install magento

http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Dropifi_Dropificontactwidget

http://connect20.magento-commerce.com/community/Dropifi_Dropificontactwidget

Help me to get a result for this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not an issue specific to you.  Today, the Magento Connect server experienced an outage which prevented any of the community extension keys from working.

The Connect server appears to be online now, so try again and it should work.

Source: https://twitter.com/magento/status/384805097315659776

**Helpful Note:**
You can download extension packages directly by using the following tool:
http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

Just paste in your Magento extension keys and Submit.  A downloadable link will appear for you to obtain the package.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem ("CONNECT ERROR: Unsupported resource type") while upgrading a 1.6 magento on PHP 5.5.
The `unpack` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) has changed.
In `downloader/lib/Mage/Archive/Tar.php`, the line

> `const FORMAT_PARSE_HEADER = 'a100name/a8mode/a8uid/a8gid/a12size/a12mtime/a8checksum/a1type/a100symlink/a6magic/a2version/a32uname/a32gname/a8devmajor/a8devminor/a155prefix/a12closer';`

must be replaced by:

> `const FORMAT_PARSE_HEADER = 'Z100name/Z8mode/Z8uid/Z8gid/Z12size/Z12mtime/Z8checksum/Z1type/Z100symlink/Z6magic/Z2version/Z32uname/Z32gname/Z8devmajor/Z8devminor/Z155prefix/Z12closer';`

Answer (score 0):

i have got this error then try following steps
first you can disable all cache
second after install extension then clear all cache and logout and login