# Paybox error - There has been an error processing your request

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I get this error after installing the [paybox extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/paybox-extension-1.html) for magento 1.8 community version,

> There has been an error processing your request
>
> Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 1068071763

Any idea what has gone wrong with it and how can I fix it?

By the way, I downloaded the paybox extension via this link http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php after following the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097292/got-an-error-in-magento-connect-for-installing-any-extension).

**EDIT:**

the content of Magento/var/report/1068071763,

```
a:4:{i:0;s:59:"Module "Quadra_Paybox" requires module "Quadra_Extensions".";i:1;s:807:"#0 C:\wamp\www\argenties_magento_2014\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(849): Mage::throwException('Module "Quadra_...')
#1 C:\wamp\www\argenties_magento_2014\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(812): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_sortModuleDepends(Array)
#2 C:\wamp\www\argenties_magento_2014\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(315): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_loadDeclaredModules()
#3 C:\wamp\www\argenties_magento_2014\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModules()
#4 C:\wamp\www\argenties_magento_2014\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#5 C:\wamp\www\argenties_magento_2014\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 C:\wamp\www\argenties_magento_2014\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}";s:3:"url";s:24:"/argenties_magento_2014/";s:11:"script_name";s:33:"/argenties_magento_2014/index.php";}
```

Comment: Paste the content of Magento/var/report/1068071763 here in your question

Comment: You need to install Quadra_Extensions module also, because of the dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error, I can conclude that

> The extension Paybox requires the installation of the Quadra_Extension
>   extension available [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/quadra-extensions.html)

The above line is written in the extension [page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/paybox-extension-1.html) itself

Check in the module config file(app/etc/modules/(NameSpace_ModuleName)).

```
    <modules>
         <(NameSpace_ModuleName)>
             <active>[true|false]</active>
             <codePool>[core|community|local]</codePool>
             <depends>
                 <(AnotherNameSpace_ModuleName) />
             </depends>
             <version>(version_number)</version>
         </(NameSpace_ModuleName)>
    </modules>
```

Comment: Hi tealou, you can accept the answer if it found you helpful.